# How can I refresh list as my database get some changed automatically without user perform refresh in android project

Tags: android

I want to refresh my list instantly when my datbase get changed but I dont want use firibase database I am using mysql database right now. plese let me know how can i do this

Comment: local database ?

Comment: You need to use LiveData or RxJava to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Todo this kind of live data refresh,
normally i suggest and use LiveData Android jetpack feature

Use this

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

https://www.journaldev.com/21168/android-livedata

Comment: I am using remote server How can I use live data model this is for sqllite

Comment: Yes you can use it with api's and many other things like this demo 
  https://androidwave.com/working-with-livedata/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a library using Devart

This library shows how to track changes within several commands. Please see link below.

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html